# Error invoking Method: Internal server error [500]

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am new to meteor js, using boilerplate stricture for an app.
In client/view folder, I have created admin folder for admin side of my project, in admin side I have a product folder, From this I can list all products, To add a new product, I added "new product" folder and put code for new product in html and js file.
Everything is working fine, But now I want to add methods to save new products.
So for this I moved product insert code in server/startup/product.js file.

```
    Meteor.startup(function () {
      Meteor.methods({
        'addProduct': function(productname,productprice,productdes){

             Products.insert({
                name: productname,
                price: productprice,
                description: productdes

            });
        },
       'sendLogMessages1' : function (){
            console.log("Hello Rahul111");
     }
    });

    });

And then I called this method to my addproduct.js file 

 var productname = event.target.productname.value;
    var productprice = event.target.productprice.value;
    var productdes = event.target.productdes.value;
    var productimg = event.target.productimg;
    Meteor.call('addProduct', productname,productprice,productdes);
```

But every time console says Error invoking Method 'addProduct': Internal server error [500]
please help me to solve this issue.
thanks in Advance.

Comment: Look at the meteor server console to see what the error is

Comment: Meteor methods don't need to be in a meteor.startup block either. And I don't know why there's a star before products.insert

Comment: * is added by default,I also tried without   meteor.startup but error remains same. Is there any package I am missing.

Comment: What's the error message you get on the server!

Comment: it is Error invoking Method 'addProduct': Internal server error [500]

Comment: But is saving records , i dont know how

Comment: That's the error message you see in the chrome console. What does the server say?

Comment: No, Server is saying nothing. Values are saving to database perfectly. I want to know why console is showing  this ERROR

Comment: Seems very strange that there's a message saying internal server error yet you don't see any errors on the server. To debug console.log all the variables you use and before and after inserting the product to the db

Comment: yes, I just want to know what is the issue , Is there any security issue. I am not using check and publish and subscribe is it because of this.

Comment: I don't know what the issue is. It says there's a server error but apparently you're not seeing one. On the client you could catch the error and print out more details. That might help. Also print to the console to debug and help you get your answer

Comment: Can you please steps to add details to database in right way.
I am creating a module product. For this I need to add/edit/delete products from database 
I am using boilerplate package.
Please explain where should I add all client and server side files.
and also please tell me for admin panel modules what to be the stricture.

Comment: Console.log(product price)

Comment: Your code looks correct. That's how you add to the db